# How to close an application or modal dialog via the taskbar when the dialog's ShowInTaskBar = false?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have an application (`mainApp`) that opens a modal dialog (`collector`) to ask for login details. The dialog has a cancel button and a standard close button in the top-right corner, and has `FormBorderStyle = FixedDialog`.

If I set `collector.ShowInTaskBar = true` I can right-click the dialog box in the taskbar and close it. The dialog disappears and the main app is still running. I can also right-click the whole group and choose 'Close all windows', which closes both the dialog and the application.

If I set `collector.ShowInTaskBar = false` I can right-click the application in the taskbar and click close, but nothing happens.

I would prefer not to show the dialog in the taskbar, but I would like the entire application to close when it is closed from the taskbar. How can I do this? If this is not possible I would settle for just closing the dialog.

Edit: the main form's FormClosing event does not get called when `ShowInTaskBar = false`

Comment: if you show login then it means data shown on the main form when it start are unrelated to user login. Therefore you can request the user login Before opening the main form. Order should be : Splash - Updater - First time setting - Login - Application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you close your forms that way, the message `WM_SYSCOMMAND` will be sent to your form window. We can catch this message with some informative params to perform according actions. Try this code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
   public Form1(){
     InitializeComponent();
   }
   bool shownModal;//This flag will be used to determine if there is some
                  //modal dialog opening.
   protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
        if (m.Msg == 0x112)//WM_SYSCOMMAND
        {
            //SC_CLOSE = 0xf060  
            if (m.WParam.ToInt32() == 0xf060 && 
                m.LParam.ToInt32() == 0 && shownModal)
            {
                //Your own code here
                //You can close the main form or close the modal dialog
                Close();
            }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);            
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: You have to turn on the flag `shownModal` before showing your dialog and turn off after that. It's just a way to deal with it, you can try another way of your own.

Answer (score 1):

Does the MainForm's Closing event get fired when you click Close in the taskbar?  If it does, and the app is being forced to stay open by the presence of the dialog windows, you could try programatically closing the dialog in the Closing event, and then letting the event run its course.

NOTE : This is all speculation, and it is a long time since I did any WinForms work so I may have the event names wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store reference to your login window in mainApp. Then you can write something like this:

```
loginWindow.Close();
```

which closes dialog window. This action can take place also inside loginwindow, for example user clicks button Close and window closes.